# "Greater" function gives me wrong order

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sorting

When I try to sort the eigenvalues of the matrix (Rho) the results seems to be in the wrong order

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

```
Rm = {{E^(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 
       2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa] \[Mu]^2 + 
     E^SuperStar[(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2)]
       SuperStar[\[Kappa]] (SuperStar[\[Mu]])^2, -I E^(-2 I t \
\[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa] \[Mu]^2 + 
     I E^SuperStar[(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2)]
       SuperStar[\[Kappa]] (SuperStar[\[Mu]])^2, 
    0}, {-I E^(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 
       2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa] \[Mu]^2 + 
     I E^SuperStar[(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2)]
       SuperStar[\[Kappa]] (SuperStar[\[Mu]])^2, -E^(-2 I t \[Sigma] \
- 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa] \[Mu]^2 - 
     E^SuperStar[(-2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2)]
       SuperStar[\[Kappa]] (SuperStar[\[Mu]])^2, 0}, {0, 0, 
    E^(2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa] \[Mu] + 
     E^(2 I t \[Sigma] - 2 t \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2) \[Kappa]^2 \[Mu]^2}};
Rho = Rm\[ConjugateTranspose].Rm ;
{\[Epsilon]1, \[Epsilon]2, \[Epsilon]3} = 
  Sort[Eigenvalues[Rho], Greater];
\[Sigma] = Sqrt[(J*\[ScriptV])^2 + B^2]; \[Mu] = 
 B - \[Sigma]; \[Kappa] = B + \[Sigma]; \[ScriptV] = 5/100;
       J = 1; \[Gamma] = 1/10; B = 0; t = 20;
\[Epsilon]1  // FullSimplify
\[Epsilon]2 // FullSimplify
\[Epsilon]3 // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Can you compare the behavior of `Sort[{1, 2, 3}, Greater]` and `Sort[{1, 2, 3}, Less]` and state which order you like better?

Comment: According to the code,  the results should be E1>E2>E3. @Arnoud Buzing

Comment: I note that you did the sorting **before** you substituted numerical values for your parameters. It is possible that `Sort[]` did little to no sorting of the *symbolic* eigenvalues, since `Greater[]` wouldn't really know what to do with things that *aren't* numbers.